# What is the simplest way to allow anonymous file upload under iis 7.0?

Tags: iis-7

I have created a separate upload website (no web pages, just a place where HTTP POST can be used) and its associated directory. I set the dir's permissions to allow r/w for network services. I can download files from the dir just fine. When I try a upload a file I get a 404 error. These files are small 1K or less text files. By my guess it should work but I can't seem to get IIS to play along...

Thanks...

Comment: Unless you've setup [webdav](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webdav) your webserver won't handle file uploads by itself.

Comment: Ok thanks. That's what I was looking for. Sometimes the hardest part is to get out of the gate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you've setup [webdav](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webdav) your webserver won't handle file uploads by itself.